# Connect Ubuntu To Active Directory

Tags: linux, active-directory

Hey, so I'm curious as to how I would be able to connect an Ubuntu machine on my network to do authentication via the Active Directory Domain Controller, also on my network. I've done a little bit of searching, but have gotten a little confused, like with Kerberos and such.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LikewiseOpen is an easy alternative for integrating Ubuntu into Active Directory environments.

Check it out here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen

Comment: Alright I tried following the linked documentation, but I couldn't join. I get this error: 9502 (0x251E) DNS_ERROR_BAD_PACKET - A bad packet was received from a DNS server. Potentially the requested address does not exist. I ran the health script and here is the output: http://chigstuff.com/text.out

Comment: According to the output posted you will get 9502 errors until added SRV records for ad.chigs.me to your DNS server 192.168.137.1

Comment: I changed the DNS server to my Domain Controller, but now I get this error: Error: Lsass Error [code 0x00080047]

40286 (0x9D5E) LW_ERROR_LDAP_SERVER_DOWN - Unknown error

Why would I be getting this? The server is running. Want me to run another health script?

Comment: If the output to "telnet ad.chigs.me 389" on stumpy-pc does not return connected to ... Escape character ... then something in your network is blocking the connection.

Comment: $ telnet ad.chigs.me 389
telnet: could not resolve ad.chigs.me/389: Name or service not known

Are there any ports that I need to have open / not blocked by a firewall? The AD server is Windows Server 2008 SP2

Comment: The "could not resolve" message indicates you're still having DNS issues. Please check that the DNS server can resolve ad.chigs.me. If you still get errors please post an updated health script output.